# std::map<std::any, std::any> trouble

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stdmap

I'm trying to make an `std:map` with `std::any` types of keys and values

Visual Studio 2017

```
std::map<std::any, std::any> m("lastname", "Ivanov");
std::cout << std::any_cast<std::string>(m["lastname"]) << std::endl;
```

getting me an

> error: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const_Ty'

Comment: Any reason to declare the `map` to use `any` when you're just adding `string`s?

Comment: It's for test reason, there will be different types

Comment: I gues `std::any` does not have a < operator.

Comment: I need to store some key-value data of any types. Maybe there are better way?

Comment: How do you compare `42`, `"hello"s`, `std::vector{4, 8, 15}` and `MyType{}`?

Comment: @Jarod42 I would have let decided this the compiler, but I saw in the std::any doc that you can't get the template type, so you can't create a global < operator.

Comment: when I use std::map<string,string>, VS getting me an error like std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair: none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

Comment: Ok I see. I need to override compare operator, thank you

Comment: `m("lastname", "Ivanov")` should be `m({{"lastname", "Ivanov"}})` anyway.

Comment: Wow I spend a lot of time THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

`std::any` doesn't have binary '<' operater (less than). The default method of how to 'index' the `std::map` elements.

Solutions could include:

1. Use another key (that has operator '<')
2. Use a custom comparator, for example:

   ```
   #include <map>
   #include <any>

   int main() {
       auto elements = std::initializer_list<std::pair<const std::any, std::any>>{};
       auto mymap = std::map(elements, [](const std::any& lhs, const std::any& rhs){return false;});
   }
   ```

Then implement the compare function instead of returning `false`.

[try it yourself](https://godbolt.org/z/M83nti)